# Slim framework 3 php-view variable

Tags: php, slim, middleware

I would like to have a variable from request ($request->getUri()->getBasePath();) always available on the templates. How can I do this e.g. with a middleware without having to pass the above as parameter to renderer->render on all routes each time ?

```
$app->get(...
   ...
  $args['basepath']=$request->getUri()->getBasePath();
  return $this->renderer->render($response, 'test.php', $args);
});
```

**UPDATE:**
This can be done after php-view 2.1.0 as so:

dependencies.php:

```
$container['renderer'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['renderer'];
    return new Slim\Views\PhpRenderer($settings['template_path']);
};
```

middleware.php:

```
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $renderer = $this->get('renderer');
    $renderer->addAttribute('uri', $request->getUri());
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Then, inside the template:

```
<?php
    $basePath=$uri->getBasePath();
    $rpath=$uri->getPath();
?>
```

Comment: added issue request: https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View/issues/21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking into [the Code](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View/blob/master/src/PhpRenderer.php) of the PhpRenderer you will see currently there is no way to specify `data` outside of the `render()` function.

You could create an issue and/or make a pull request to support that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Version 2.1.0 of PHP-View now supports setting template variables before you render. See https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View#template-variables.